# Using a non-literal value in Apache Derby's OFFSET clause

Tags: derby, offset, sql-limit

Using Derby, is it possible to offset by a value from the query rather than an integer literal?

When I run this query, it complains about the value I've given to the offset clause.

```
select
    PRIZE."NAME" as "Prize Name",
    PRIZE."POSITION" as "Position",
    (select 
            PARTICIPANT."NAME"
    from PARTICIPANT
    order by POINTS desc
    offset PRIZE."POSITION" rows fetch next 1 row only  <-- notice I'm trying to pass in a value to offset by
    ) as "Participant"
from PRIZE
```

With the expectation that the results would look like this:

```
| Prize Name   | Position | Participant   |
|--------------|----------|---------------|
| Gold medal   | 1        | Mari Loudi    |
| Silver medal | 2        | Keesha Vacc   |
| Bronze medal | 3        | Melba Hammit  |
| Hundredth    | 100      | James Thornby |
```

The [documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html) suggests that it's possible to pass in a value from java code, but I'm trying to use a value from the query itself.

By the way, this is just an example schema to illustrate the point.

I know there are other ways to achieve the ranking, but I'm specifically interested if there's a way to pass values to the offset clause.